# Use custom post type taxonomy between cpt slug and name

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, slug

I'm building a site for a car dealership and I've created a `CPT: Cars` and a `Custom Taxonomy: Brand`

Each car has one brand (Obviously), but I want to display them like this:
`dealership.com/cars/%brand%/%car-name%`

I'm currently using the [Custom Post Type UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) plugin but I'm completely comfortable with code.

Also, I don't see the option for taxonomies to show as an archive.
The only way they show up is `dealership.com/brand/%brand-name%` but `dealership.com/brands` throws a 404. **There seems to not be an archive page for taxonomies :(**

Comment: There's no such thing as an archive of taxonomies unfortunately.

Comment: @cameronjonesweb Well that seems stupid. Thanks for pointing it out! I was pulling my hair out on this.

Comment: archives are always for posts as the main query is a post query, you can't have a "term archive" unless you build one from scratch